# My computer name keeps changing when I plug it into a Thunderbolt display

Tags: thunderbolt

Every day I come into the office and plug my mac into my Thunderbolt display. It says the name "yourcomputer" is in use and renames it "yourcomputer-2" (or -3 or -4 ...). How do I make it stop?

Comment: Do you have the Mac hooked up to Ethernet through the Thunderbolt display?

Comment: Yes, it's ethernet through thunderbolt.

Comment: is the name "yourcomputer" unique on your work's network? i.e. are there other people with Mac's that **might** have the same computer name or are you also connecting via a second network such as wi-fi?

Comment: another possibility, do you plug into the same display every day or do you hot desk between multiple available Thunderbolt displays?

Comment: nope, one laptop, one display, one unique name on the network

Comment: Are you also connecting to Wifi / Wireless network at the same time, that is the same network?

Comment: @chrismealy Do you turn the Thunderbolt display off when you unplug the Mac to leave?

Comment: Probably I solved by disabling wake on wlan. I think it was time machine's fault, who was actin as a sleep proxy. Are you still having this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try making your hostname permanent by typing this command into the Terminal:

```
sudo scutil --set HostName yourcomputer
```

My hostname kept changing when I connected to the network because the router was broadcasting a different hostname, and this fixed it.

Comment: In my case is "ComputerName" that keeps changing. This does nothing more than setting it from system preferences. A few seconds later it will return to "computername (n)". This is the [log](http://hastebin.com/ozutupapeg) of what happens exactly after it changes.